# Path pointing to the non-existent file

Tags: python, r, spell-checking

I want to test `spell4french`, spell checking package for the French language in R, by running the `Gutenberg.ipynb` notebook provided in the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/camilodlt/spelll4french/blob/main/Gutenberg.ipynb) for the Python usage.

The path to the `/content/drive/MyDrive/Gutenberg/test_2_half_M.txt` file (indicated in the third cell) doesn't exist in the repo:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Gutenberg/test_2_half_M.txt'
```

I don't understand either what that file refers to or how it has to be formatted, as it was not specified.

I posted the same [issue](https://github.com/camilodlt/spelll4french/issues/4) which hasn't been answered yet.

Do you have any idea what this is about?

Comment: how about changing the path and/or locating the file in a place where you want it to be?

Comment: I would've done that, but it seems that the file `test_2_half_M.txt` is completely missing from the both branches of the repo (furthermore, its only occurrence appears in the `.gitignore`). Even if I wanted to add my own file and locate it, I don't have a clue what kind of file I should create.